# Manipulate the date picker view

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am using the ui date picker view to show the date.And after using this my output is like this-

[image]

But i want to change the format of date. And my desire output is

please help me how to implement this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this-

change the mode of the date picker to date.